# how to create a lucid vm with xen?

Tags: ubuntu, xen, ubuntu-8.04

i've just installed xen on my ubuntu 8.04.

When i enter `xen-create-image --ip=192.168.0.200 --hostname=newhost`

i get an hardy vm. but i would like to have a "newer" lucid vm. :/

when i use `xen-create-image --ip=192.168.0.200 --hostname=newhost --dist=lucid` xen tells me, that there is no hook directory for lucid.

is it possible with xen to install a lucid vm on a hardy host?

if yes, how?

thanks for any reply :)

Comment: Which version of xen-tools package do you have installed? Also, take a look in /usr/lib/xen-tools/ to see which distributions are available.

Comment: i've installed xen-tools 3.9-4 and in /usr/lib/xen-tools/ there is no lucid :(

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu dropped support for running a dom0 after 8.04. After much frustration trying to get 10.04 domU's running on 8.04 I switched to the recently released Debian 6.0 Squeeze.

Squeeze ships with Xen 4.0 and [installation was a breeze](http://wiki.debian.org/Xen#Installation_on_squeeze). I'm running Lucid, Hardy and Squeeze domU's and am very happy Debian has returned to supporting Xen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try removing the Ubuntu supplied xen-tools package and try installing the latest Xen-tools 4.2 from [here](http://www.xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/releases.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `/etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf` , and check for a mirrors section.

You should have a line like "`mirror_lucid = http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`" that tells xen where to fetch that release. If not, try to mimic the older mirror lines there and add that mirror.

You should know that the sample line I've given you is taken from a xen-tools 4.2 version, so it may not be the same.